# ng-select selected

Tags: angular, angular7

estoy usando ng-select y quiero que la primera opción sea la que esté seleccionada por defecto con su correspondiente value

```
                <ng-select [searchable] [virtualScroll] name="nombre_paciente" [(ngModel)]='contacto.paciente_asociado'>
                    <ng-option value="5348" selected>Ningún paciente seleccionado</ng-option>
                    <ng-option value="{{fcontacto.historia}}" *ngFor="let fcontacto of pacientes">{{fcontacto.historia}} - {{fcontacto.nombre}}</ng-option>
                </ng-select>
```

Os dejo una imagen de como se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: has probado en lugar de `selected` a poner `ng-selected="true"`?

Comment: A tu modelo 'contacto.paciente_asociado' dale el valor de 5348 por defecto, y en el 'ng-option' que quieres por defecto dale el valor 5348 a la propiedad 'value'.
Dado que el ngModel va a tener el mismo valor que tu ng-option se va a tomar ese por defecto

Comment: @DavidLeal gracias a tu respuesta pude resolverlo, muchas gracias